# MVC passing Model to Controller issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Code is VB, using MVC 4(possibly. 5)
I am trying to figure out two issues with my code, and have, to date, been unable to find anything that causes my current issues.
First, when the model is passed back, it seems to be nothing(all elements contained within are nothing).  This is an issue.  I have looked online and have been unable to find a solution(or a suggestion of what the issue is).
Secondly, when one of the buttons is hit, it does not go immediately to the correct HttpPost method, instead cycling through them(in an erratic order).  This is also a concern.

This is the Controller.  The Model is being passed to the View by the Index, which is marked as httpget.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Namespace Test
    <HttpPost()> _
    Function SelectUser(ByVal Model As Test.Models.AdminModel) As ActionResult
        Return View("Index", Model)
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function AddEnv(ByVal Model As Test2.Models.AdminModel) As ActionResult
        Return View("Index", Model)
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function RemoveEnv(ByVal Model As Test.Models.AdminModel) As ActionResult
        Return View("Index", Model)
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function AddApp(ByVal Model As Test.Models.AdminModel) As ActionResult
        Return View("Index", Model)
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function RemoveApp(ByVal Model As Test.Models.AdminModel) As ActionResult
        Return View("Index", Model)
    End Function
End Namespace
```

Here is the View.  The model seems to bind correctly(I get intellisense)

```
@ModelType Test.Test.Models.AdminModel
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Admin"
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Admin.vbhtml"
End Code  

<table>
<tr>
    @Using (Html.BeginForm("SelectUser", "Admin", method:=FormMethod.Post))
        @<td>Username:&nbsp;</td>
        @<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.UserAccount.Username)</td>
        @<td><a href="javascript:$('form').submit();" class='BUTTON' style="display:   inline-block; height: 30px; width: 80px"><span>Select User</span></a></td>
        @<td><input type ="submit" Class="BUTTON" style="display: inline-block; height:   30px; width: 80px" value ="Login"/></td>
    End Using
</tr>

<tr>
    @Using (Html.BeginForm("AddApp", "Admin", method:=FormMethod.Post))
        @<td>Add App:&nbsp;</td>
        @<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.NewApp)</td>
        @<td><a href="javascript:$('form').submit();" class='BUTTON' style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; width: 80px"><span>Add App</span></a></td>
        @<td><input type ="submit" Class="BUTTON" style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; width: 80px" value ="Login"/></td>
    End Using

</tr>
<tr>
    @Using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveApp", "Admin", method:=FormMethod.Post))
        @<td>Remove App:</td>
        @<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.AppList, Model.AppList)</td>
        @<td><a href="javascript:$('form').submit();" class='BUTTON' style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; width: 80px"><span>Remove App</span></a></td>
        @<td><input type ="submit" Class="BUTTON" style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; width: 80px" value ="Login"/></td>
    End Using
</tr>

<tr>
    @Using (Html.BeginForm("AddEnv", "Admin", method:=FormMethod.Post))
        @<td>Add Env:&nbsp;</td>
        @<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.NewEnv)</td>
        @<td><a href="javascript:$('form').submit();" class='BUTTON' style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; width: 80px"><span>Add Env</span></a></td>
        @<td><input type ="submit" Class="BUTTON" style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; width: 80px" value ="Login"/></td>
    End Using
</tr>
<tr>
    @Using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveEnv", "Admin", method:=FormMethod.Post))
        @<td>Remove Env:</td>
        @<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.EnvList, Model.EnvList)</td>
        @<td><a href="javascript:$('form').submit();" class='BUTTON' style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; width: 80px"><span>Remove Env</span></a></td>
        @<td><input type ="submit" Class="BUTTON" style="display: inline-block; height:     30px; width: 80px" value ="Login"/></td>
    End Using
</tr>

</table>
```

Finally, the Model:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Namespace Test.Models
Public Class AdminModel
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="User Name field is required"), Display(Name:="User Name")>
    Public UserAccount As User2.User
    Public AppList As SelectList
    Public EnvList As SelectList
    Public PermissionsTable As DataTable
    Public NewEnv As String
    Public NewApp As String
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: You see all your actions being executed becasue `javascript:$('form').submit()` will submit all forms on your page.

Comment: That is indeed it.  Thanks.  Is there a way to get it to only submit a specific form?

Comment: Try `$("#formid").submit()` and give your forms ids.

Comment: That fixes that problem.  Thanks.  Between the two of you, I believe you have answered the question.  Not sure where to put the answer(Well, when I can)

Comment: Mark the current answer since it best matches your title. Just glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use properties in your model, not public variable.

```
Public Property UserAccount As User2.User
    Public Property AppList As SelectList
    Public Property EnvList As SelectList
    Public Property PermissionsTable As DataTable
    Public Property NewEnv As String
    Public Property NewApp As String
```

Comment: That change has been made, although it does not solve either issue, it is very good advice.

Comment: @Archmage1 Does NewEnv and NewApp work? I'm not sure if the other will work since they are objects.

Comment: Hm... then again... it does indeed seem to have resolved the binding issue(partially)  It only bound the item in the form that it registered as clicked.  Missed that, since it seems to be choosing which post was called at random.  That is workable, although not ideal.